# Is it possible "Database Synchronization"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem and not sure if this is possible. My web application has a database and i'm using a mysql workbench and using wamp server.

My web app has a database name healthcare, and if I import again another database with the same tables, etc but addition data. I want the first database to be updated only with new values but not replaced.

Is it possible?

Edit: I searched in the net and other related sources and I manage to set my phpmyadmin "Ignore multiple statement errors". When I import the second database (.sql with same tables but with new data) it does not update the first database but the message is successful. Please help, I'll appreciate any help...

Comment: this is the scenario, my web application is created by JSP. I want to use it in two different location (main and branch) and i'm using VPN hamachi. The main will run the web app in apache tomcat then the branch will connect via the ip. So the database is synchronized but connection is relying in the internet. If there's no internet no connection, and that my problem, I have no backup if there's no internet... My plan is the branch will also run the web app but with their own database, if internet is available the branch will send their database so the main will synchronize it

Comment: please help if there a better way... I will very appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

in the past ive searched for tools to do some similar database sync tasks - in my experience ive found that none are free & reliable.

have you tried writing some queries to do this manually?

first thing that comes to mind would be figuring out a key you can use to evaluate each row and determine if you should copy said record from database A to database B.

afterwards you could simply do an INSERT(SELECT)

```
INSERT INTO healthcare_DESTINATION.table (SELECT * FROM healthcare_SOURCE WHERE some_condition = 1);
```

obviously this is the simplified version - but i've done something very similar utilizing timestamps (eg only copy rows newer than the newest row in the destination table)

hope this helps

Comment: oh I see... so the only way is to make a script? ok thankz...
how about in CSV?

Comment: theres a possibility of other solutions but id need a little more information, what do your tables look like? - what exactly is stoping you from overwriting them?  im assuming this isnt a development environment / production environment clone setup - am i correct?

Comment: this is the scenario, my web application is created by JSP. I want to use it in two different location (main and branch) and i'm using VPN hamachi. The main will run the web app in apache tomcat then the branch will connect via the ip. So the database is synchronized but connection is relying in the internet. If there's no internet no connection, and that my problem, I have no backup if there's no internet... 

My plan is the branch will also run the web app but with their own database, if internet is available the branch will send their database so the main will synchronize it.